# JSON Object sorting by name which is date in string form

Tags: java, json, api

I am brand new to Java and I am currently trying to sort out a JSON response from an API by its (string) name which is actually the date. It gives me the date & time as a JSONObject which contain strings of information. I was wondering if anyone has ever sorted JSONObjects by their "String name" and sorted them by dates.

Here is a snippet of the JSON response. As you can see it jumps wildly from 3rd May to 23rd April. There is another object for the 2nd of May further below which I haven't posted for the sake of simplicity.

```json
{
  "2019-05-03 12:30:00": {
    "3. low": "1180.6000",
    "5. volume": "238455",
    "1. open": "1181.3800",
    "2. high": "1185.5200",
    "4. close": "1185.4500"
  },
  "2019-04-23 10:30:00": {
    "3. low": "1257.6000",
    "5. volume": "176972",
    "1. open": "1259.8450",
    "2. high": "1264.5500",
    "4. close": "1264.1100"
  }
}
```

I have tried calling the object name via `keys()`. ie. `JSONOBJECT.names()` and converting to date via `SimpleDateFormat`, however naturally `JSONObject.name()` does not contain any string nested in that object.

I'd still need to retrieve the 3. low: 1180 strings, convert them to float and pass them through a statistical test for the project.

Comment: Your example array seems to be incorrect, missing its label and square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

## Java API for JSON Binding (JSON-B)

There are many Java-based JSON processing libraries to choose from. Some follow the standard [Java API for JSON Binding (JSON-B)](http://json-b.net) API defined by [JSR 367](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367) as part of [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition), and some do not. One that does is the reference implementation, [Eclipse Yasson](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/yasson/).

If using Maven on your project, here are the current entries for your POM.

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.json.bind/jakarta.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

## Correct array notation

While I am no JSON expert, your sample seems malformed.

- Need square brackets to wrap an array.
- Each object needs a label, such as `"quote"` here. You are improperly using the date-time value as the label, while it should be another member of each quote object.

And fix the date-time strings to comply with ISO 8601, the standard formats used by default in the *java.time* classes.

```json
[
  {
    "when": "2019-05-03T12:30:00",
    "low": "1180.6000",
    "volume": "238455",
    "open": "1181.3800",
    "high": "1185.5200",
    "close": "1185.4500"
  },
  {
    "when": "2019-04-23T10:30:00",
    "low": "1257.6000",
    "volume": "176972",
    "open": "1259.8450",
    "high": "1264.5500",
    "close": "1264.1100"
  }
]
```

## Define a class

I suggest you parse each stock quote as a Java objects in the shape of a class you define.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class StockQuote implements Comparable<StockQuote>
{
    public LocalDateTime when;
    public Long volume;
    public BigDecimal high, low, open, close;

    // --------|  Constructors  |------------------------

    public StockQuote ()
    {
        // No code needed here. No-arg constructor required for use with JSON-B.
    }

    public StockQuote ( LocalDateTime when , Long volume , BigDecimal low , BigDecimal high , BigDecimal open , BigDecimal close )
    {
        this.when = when;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
        this.open = open;
        this.close = close;
    }

    // --------|  Object  |------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        StockQuote that = ( StockQuote ) o;
        return Objects.equals( this.when , that.when);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return Objects.hash( this.when );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return new StringJoiner( " | " , StockQuote.class.getSimpleName() + "{ " , " }" )
                .add( "when=" + when )
                .add( "volume=" + volume )
                .add( "high=" + high )
                .add( "low=" + low )
                .add( "open=" + open )
                .add( "close=" + close )
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo ( StockQuote that )
    {
        return this.when.compareTo( that.when );
    }

}
```

## Parse as collection of objects

Prepare the JSON processor.

```java
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
```

Define some input.

```java
String json = "[\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"when\": \"2019-05-03T12:30:00\",\n" +
        "    \"low\": \"1180.6000\",\n" +
        "    \"volume\": \"238455\",\n" +
        "    \"open\": \"1181.3800\",\n" +
        "    \"high\": \"1185.5200\",\n" +
        "    \"close\": \"1185.4500\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"when\": \"2019-04-23T10:30:00\",\n" +
        "    \"low\": \"1257.6000\",\n" +
        "    \"volume\": \"176972\",\n" +
        "    \"open\": \"1259.8450\",\n" +
        "    \"high\": \"1264.5500\",\n" +
        "    \"close\": \"1264.1100\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]\n"
;
```

Parse and collect those quote objects.

```
List < StockQuote > quotes = jsonb.fromJson( json , new ArrayList < StockQuote >() {}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() );
```

Lastly, sort your collection.

```java
Collections.sort( quotes );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "quotes:\n" + quotes );
```

> quotes:
>
> [StockQuote{ when=2019-05-03T12:30 | volume=238455 | high=1185.5200 | low=1180.6000 | open=1181.3800 | close=1185.4500 }, StockQuote{ when=2019-04-23T10:30 | volume=176972 | high=1264.5500 | low=1257.6000 | open=1259.8450 | close=1264.1100 }]

Success.

We can tolerate the numbering on your object member labels.

On each member of our `StockQuote` class, add a `@JsonbProperty` annotation. See the [Json Binding Users Guide](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/docs/user-guide.html#changing-property-names).

```java
@JsonbProperty ( "0. when" )
public LocalDateTime when;
@JsonbProperty ( "5. volume" )
public Long volume;
@JsonbProperty ( "2. high" )
public BigDecimal high;
@JsonbProperty ( "3. low" )
public BigDecimal low;
@JsonbProperty ( "1. open" )
public BigDecimal open;
@JsonbProperty ( "4. close" )
public BigDecimal close;
```

Let's put back those numbered labels.

```java
    String json = "    [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"0. when\": \"2019-05-03T12:30:00\",\n" +
            "        \"3. low\": \"1180.6000\",\n" +
            "        \"5. volume\": \"238455\",\n" +
            "        \"1. open\": \"1181.3800\",\n" +
            "        \"2. high\": \"1185.5200\",\n" +
            "        \"4. close\": \"1185.4500\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"0. when\": \"2019-04-23T10:30:00\",\n" +
            "        \"3. low\": \"1257.6000\",\n" +
            "        \"5. volume\": \"176972\",\n" +
            "        \"1. open\": \"1259.8450\",\n" +
            "        \"2. high\": \"1264.5500\",\n" +
            "        \"4. close\": \"1264.1100\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]"
    ;
```

And we now get the same successful results.

## Date-time as string

Though I do not recommend it, you could keep the date-time value as a `String` in your Java `StockQuote` class. Your inputs happen to be chronological when sorting alphabetically.

Change the type of the `when` member from `LocalDateTime` on the `StockQuote` class to `String`.

```java
@JsonbProperty ( "0. when" )
public String when;
```

Undo our fix to the input date-time strings.

```java
    String json = "    [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"0. when\": \"2019-05-03 12:30:00\",\n" +
            "        \"3. low\": \"1180.6000\",\n" +
            "        \"5. volume\": \"238455\",\n" +
            "        \"1. open\": \"1181.3800\",\n" +
            "        \"2. high\": \"1185.5200\",\n" +
            "        \"4. close\": \"1185.4500\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"0. when\": \"2019-04-23 10:30:00\",\n" +
            "        \"3. low\": \"1257.6000\",\n" +
            "        \"5. volume\": \"176972\",\n" +
            "        \"1. open\": \"1259.8450\",\n" +
            "        \"2. high\": \"1264.5500\",\n" +
            "        \"4. close\": \"1264.1100\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]"
    ;
```

Alternatively, you could keep the `when` member as a `LocalDateTime`. Add an `@JsonbDateFormat` annotation to specify the format of the incoming data.

```java
@JsonbProperty ( "0. when" )
@JsonbDateFormat ("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public LocalDateTime when;
```